# Question about finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hello everyone I read on my notes this proposition:

Given a field $K$ and $R=K[T]$, let $M$ be a (left) finitely generated $R$-module; then $M$ is a torsion module if and only if $\dim_K(M)<\infty$.

Since it has already been stated that $M$ is finitely generated, $\dim_K(M)$ must be something different from the number of generators of $M$, then my question is: what does $\dim_K(M)$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

When $M$ is an $R$-module and $R$ is a $K$-vector space, then $M$ is also a $K$-vector space.

Answer (score 0):

The generators in this example generate $M$ over $R$ *as an $R$-module*. Those generators don't necessarily form a $K$-basis.

For example, the ring $K[X]$ as a $K[X]$-module is generated by $1 \in K[X]$, but its basis as a $K$-vector space is $\{1,X,X^2,X^3,\dots\}$. Note that the former is finite but the latter is not.